# Converting nested query into join

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, postgresql, join, insert

I wanted to convert the following nested query into a join.

```
query = """ INSERT INTO ptable
            (a,b,c)
            (SELECT %d, 'valll',id
                                FROM btable
                                WHERE e = %d
                                AND f = %d);
         """ %(Data1,data2, data3)
```

Comment: describe your question properly first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a nested query.

For a nested query you need to have many tables in the same select.

Comment: Nestes as in Select within an insert.

Comment: @user977933 You can't use a `JOIN` in this situation. You're doing it right!

Comment: I have around 15000 records to insert in the database. So i wanted to improve the performance of my queries. And since joins are faster, i wanted to convert the above query into a equivalent join statement.

Comment: ok... Thanks :) Please let me know if there are any more suggestions to improve performance of my query.

Comment: Possibly add indexes to the columns used in the where clause.